# JAVA - Weird NoClassDefFoundError in : com/lowagie/textDocumentException

Tags: java, itext, noclassdeffounderror

This is the situation. I need to add PDF generation to a program that already has PNG generation. Initially the 2 classes involved are : 
**`ActionUsuels`** From where the constructor of **`CaptureImage3D`** is called.

When I added the PDF generation I added a method at the `CaptureImage3D` class. 
Before adding the PDF generation, the PNG generation worked correctly. But now when I try to do the PNG generation, I get  a  : `NoClassDefFoundError`: `com/lowagie/text/DocumentException`.

I know it means that  the class : `DocumentException` (from the itext jar) can't be read from the classpath but :

1. The PDF generation method is NEVER called.
2. The exception is generated before entering the constructor of `CaptureImage3D`.
3. Consider the following PDF generation method:

`Code:`

```
  public void captureImagePDF(File imageFile)
  {

        System.out.println("Pdf appelé");

        // Dimension (en pixels) de l'image a sauvegarder dans le fichier
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(512, 512);

        // On recupere l'image (pixmap) rendue par le canvas 3D offscreen
        BufferedImage myBufferedImage = offScreenCanvas.getOffScreenImage(dim);

        // On recupere le contexte graphique de l'image finale de sortie
        Graphics2D gc = myBufferedImage.createGraphics();

        gc.drawImage(myBufferedImage, 0, 0, null);

        Document myPDF = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);

        PdfWriter myWriter = null;

        try 
        {
            myWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(myPDF, new FileOutputStream(imageFile));
        } 


        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        catch (DocumentException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        myPDF.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = myWriter.getDirectContent();
        cb.saveState();
        Image image = null;

        try {
            image = Image.getInstance(myBufferedImage,null);
        } 

        catch (BadElementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
                cb.addImage(image);
        } 
        catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }


  }
```

When I comment all the try/catch blocs, everything works fine !!!

I repeat again: captureImagePDF is never called. And even the constructor of `CaptureImage3D` is never accessed. (it should be, but the exception is raised before). And yes, I have itext in the classpath.

I find it weird the fact that a piece of code, that is never called anywhere, causes the apparition of the exception!

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications!

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Why not put the missing class on the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have a catch for `DocumentException` means that the loader has to load the class, so that the system can catch it. :-)

If you want to avoid having to have the iText jar in your classpath, catch something higher up, or (like you said) don't catch at all. :-P

Comment: This is correct. The classloader will load all classes that are "statically" required by the executing code.

Comment: But I imported the specific class: 

import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;

And I've put the itext jar in the Java Build Path -> Libraries

What's wrong ?

Comment: @Amokrane: The build path lists jars for building. You also need the same jar in the classpath, so that it's available at run time. :-)

Comment: I used the following compilation directive : 
javac -d ./class -classpath .;./Java3D/lib/j3dcore.jar;./Java3D/j3dutils.jar;./Java3D/lib/vecmath.jar;./librairies/itext-1.3.6.jar ./src/*.java 

So as you can see, the jar is in the classpath isn't it ? (itext-1.3.6.jar)

Comment: @Amokrane: You also have to specify it in the classpath when you _run_ your program. Specifying the classpath when you compile it does not "bake" it into the program, sorry. :-(

Comment: Oh man, yes sure ! Sorry for misunderstanding you, I'm such a looser ^^. It's working now that I have added the jar in the classpath at run time. Thank you!