# dynamic report export pdf class not found exception error

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to implement Dynamic Report in java using the
dynamic report open source library.

my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

my java code:

```
 List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
             employeeList.add(new Employee("1", "Selva"));
               report()//create new report design
                 .columns(
                    Columns.column("ID", "id", String.class),
                    Columns.column("Name", "name" , String.class) 
                  ) //adds columns
                 .setDataSource(employeeList)
                 .toPdf(new FileOutputStream(new File("D://selvapdf.pdf"))); //export report to pdf
```

This code is thorwing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ExporterTransform.pdf(ExporterTransform.java:440)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ExporterTransform.transform(ExporterTransform.java:134)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.export(JasperReportBuilder.java:891)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toPdf(JasperReportBuilder.java:731)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toPdf(JasperReportBuilder.java:720)
    at com.sample.dynamicreport.App.main(App.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

Why dynamic report module does not have this dependency? Whether I should add or any other new approach is there?
Below is the output of dependency:tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dynamicreport 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6/itext-2.1.7.js6.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6/itext-2.1.7.js6.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6/itext-2.1.7.js6.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.3.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.434 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-26T11:23:22+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dynamicreport: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sample:dynamicreport:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sourceforge.dynamicreports:dynamicreports-core:jar:6.1.0 -> net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.9.0 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js6 from/to jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/): Access denied to http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6/itext-2.1.7.js6.pom. Error code 407, Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  ) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I use https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF its an update for iText. Migrating really legacy(like <2010) was really easy. If u r locked in to "dynamicreports" thenyou will need to try and fix "NoClassDefFoundError". here it is in OpenPdf https://github.com/pretix/OpenPDF/blob/master/openpdf/src/main/java/com/lowagie/text/DocumentException.java

Comment: Thanks Nigel, I have to use the dynamic report open source module i hope it internally using itext for that only I am going with itext

Comment: please upvote @hc_dev ans if it fixes your issue or if hc_dev ans not fix let us know

Comment: Hi Madhesh, please [edit] your question and add output of both maven commands (as you already did in comment + as Nigel suggests). We're close to the solution 

Comment: @Madhesh Thanks for updating. I found a possible _407/proxy issue_, researched and updated my answer. Please always monitor maven-logging closely, especially when behind a proxy :-(

Comment: @hc_dev, Thanks I will  implement the same and update you

Comment: @hc_dev, thank you so much it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Missing dependency `iText` ?

Probably you are missing a dependency called `iText` which is needed for exporting to PDF. Thus the compiler throws a **NoClassDefFoundError** saying that following class is missing: `com.lowagie.text.DocumentException`.

#### Resolution 0:

Either **re-import your maven project** (`mvn clean install`) and make sure that dependency `iText` or at least a class called `com.lowagie.text.DocumentException` is in the classpath.

Or you could **use a newer release** from [**DynamicReport**'s GitHub repository](https://github.com/dynamicreports/dynamicreports).
This is based on [Jasper Reports](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports) version *6.5.1*, which again uses **iText** for exporting reports to PDF.

If you search for `iText` within the dependencies for [JasperReports 6.1.0 on Maven](https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.5.1/jar), you will find:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.js6</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  <!-- lines omitted -->
</dependency>
```

This dependency should work with your *DynamicReports version 6.1.0*. So you could **add it separately to your POM**.

See also: [Similar NoClassDefFound-error question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240447/java-weird-noclassdeffounderror-in-com-lowagie-textdocumentexception)

---

After clarifying and updating the question by **listing/resolving the dependencies** in your POM via suggested commands:

- [`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) (Maven's guide to display dependency conflicts by expanding the dependency-tree: downloading them before)
- [`mvn dependency:resolve`](https://grep.codeconsult.ch/2010/07/08/list-all-your-maven-dependencies/) (just tries to downloading all dependencies/JARs)

.. there seems to be following (underlying) root-cause.

#### Issue seems

When Maven tries to resolve or download the dependency from external repositories, there was this **proxy-related access-error** ([HTTP status 407](https://httpstatuses.com/407)):

> Error code 407, Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )

Seems your are behind a proxy which either prevents accessing the remote POM and/or downloading the JAR dependency.
There are 2 possible solutions:

#### Resolution 1: Setup Maven to work with a proxy

See this question and answers on [How to access a Maven Repository from behind a Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855339/can-access-maven-repository-from-behind-proxy-need-help). This will tell you how to edit your Maven `settings.xml` for proxy-related configuration, as well as how to setup **CNTLM** or **Wagon HTTP lightweight** Maven extension.

#### Resolution 2: Download & install missing dependency manually

First **download the JAR file manually** from Jaspersoft's repository (JFrog Artifactory) via their browser page: [itext-2.1.7.js6.jar](https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6/itext-2.1.7.js6.jar)

Then [**install this 3rd party JAR**](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) to your local Maven repo.

Comment: thanks, I am using the updated dependency from maven. But the dependency does not include itext in it,

Comment: @Madhesh Did you list dependencies via [mvn dependency:resolve](https://grep.codeconsult.ch/2010/07/08/list-all-your-maven-dependencies/)? If `itext` not listed, try including it separately.

Comment: But include __without <scope>__, so it will not only be included at compile time, but also at _runtime_.

Comment: When I run the command I am getting this error, Failed to collect dependencies at net.sourceforge.dynamicreports:dynamicreports-core:jar:6.1.0 -> net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.9.0 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js6 from/to jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io: Access denied to http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6/itext-2.1.7.js6.pom.

Comment: would be good value to show the dependecy tree with 'mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose' then update your question with the output so we can see whats actually there

Comment: @NigelSavage That will definitely help. Good command to show the root-cause here